# Reinterpret casting pointers to standard-layout types with common prefixes

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

Let's say I have the following types:

```
struct Common { int a, b, c; };
struct Full { int a, b, c; uint64_t x, y, z; };
```

`Common` and `Full` are standard-layout types, where `Common` is a prefix of `Full`. So if I put both in a union:

```
union U {
    Common c;
    Full f;
};
```

I would be allowed to read through `c` even if `f` was the active member per 
[[class.mem]/23](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#23).

Now the question is - is there a way for me, given a `Full const*`, to get a `Common const*` in a non-UB way?

```
void foo(Full const* f) {
    Common c1;
    memcpy(&c1, f, sizeof(c1)); // this obviously works, but I don't want
                                // to be copying all this stuff

    auto c2 = reinterpret_cast<Common const*>(f); // is this ok?
        // c2 and f are pointer-interconvertible iff f comes from a U
        // but why does that U actually need to exist?

    auto u = reinterpret_cast<U const*>(f); // ok per basic.lval/8.6??
    auto c3 = &u->c;                        // ok per class.mem/23??
}
```

Comment: "pointer-interconvertible" is a property of objects, not types. If there is no union, then the result of the `reinterpret_cast` still points to `*f`.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah but isn't it a little odd to require an irrelevant object of an irrelevant type?

Comment: Not really - it's an exception to the type system that exists only for C compatibility. Recall that P0137R0 would have outlawed the whole thing outright.

Comment: @T.C. Can't recall that which I never knew :) Also I don't understand that paper...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: reinterpret casting an object address to a different class and accessing through the pointer is undefined behaviour.

I think the reason is to enable more easy alias analysis by the compiler.
If the compiler can assume that an Object of Type X cannot alias an object of unrelated Type Y, even if they happen to be layout compatible, then it may be able to perform optimizations that it could not do otherwise.

```
struct X
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct Y
{
  int c;
  int d;
};

void updateXY(X *x, Y* y)
{
   x->a = y->c;
   x->b = y->c; // if *x and *y could alias, y->c would have to be reloaded
}

void updateXX(X *x, X* xx)
{
   x->a = xx->a;
   x->b = xx->a; // the compiler must reload xx->a because x and xx may alias
}
```

In fact gcc and clang do optimize updateXY more than updateXX, because it considers the aliasing.

```
updateXY(X*, Y*):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi] // cache y->c
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi+4], eax
  ret
updateXX(X*, X*):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi] // reload y->c
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi+4], eax
  ret
```

It does not seem to make a difference for alias analysis whether a union between `X` and `Y` is visible to the compiler, i.e. the optimization is performed regardless. So in practice code that passed around pointers to non-active union members may still break. For your usecase of passing `const` pointers this is should be irrelevant.